# Can't enable telegram bot with webhook in virtual machine

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, webhooks

I use a bot in the ubuntu virtual machine and where Host I don’t know what address to write down. I used ngrok and entered something like this:

```
WEBHOOK_HOST = 'https://9339-31-41-61-134.eu.ngrok.io'
WEBHOOK_PORT = 80
```

It does nothing, tried another 127.0.0.1. Either an error, or launch, but no response when contacting the bot. Please send

```
import json
import telebot
import time
import requests
from decimal import Decimal as dec
from telebot import types
from telebot.types import InputMediaPhoto, InputMediaVideo
import psycopg2
import cherrypy
import config

WEBHOOK_HOST = '94.228.115.35'
WEBHOOK_PORT = 443
WEBHOOK_LISTEN = '0.0.0.0'

WEBHOOK_SSL_CERT = './webhook_cert.pem'  
WEBHOOK_SSL_PRIV = './webhook_pkey.pem'  

WEBHOOK_URL_BASE = "https://%s:%s" % (WEBHOOK_HOST, WEBHOOK_PORT)
WEBHOOK_URL_PATH = "/%s/" % (config.token)

cherrypy.config.update({
    'server.socket_host': WEBHOOK_LISTEN,
    'server.socket_port': WEBHOOK_PORT,
    'server.ssl_module': 'builtin',
    'server.ssl_certificate': WEBHOOK_SSL_CERT,
    'server.ssl_private_key': WEBHOOK_SSL_PRIV
})

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.token)

class WebhookServer(object):
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        if 'content-length' in cherrypy.request.headers and \
                        'content-type' in cherrypy.request.headers and \
                        cherrypy.request.headers['content-type'] == 'application/json':
            length = int(cherrypy.request.headers['content-length'])
            json_string = cherrypy.request.body.read(length).decode("utf-8")
            update = telebot.types.Update.de_json(json_string)
            bot.process_new_updates([update])
            return ''
        else:
            cherrypy.process.wspbus.bus.exit()


while True:
    bot.remove_webhook()
    bot.set_webhook(url=WEBHOOK_URL_BASE + WEBHOOK_URL_PATH,
                    certificate=open(WEBHOOK_SSL_CERT, 'r'))
    cherrypy.quickstart(WebhookServer(), WEBHOOK_URL_PATH, {'/': {}})
    print("REBOOT!")
    time.sleep(5)
```